# Grabbing string from database and putting it into variable, the variable contains 2 extra \\

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-2.0

A user can enter a conn string such as:
`(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB`, ef core takes care of putting this into my table and stores it correctly. however when i read it back out and try to use it, it contains an extra 2 \ e.g.`(LocalDb)\\\\MSSQLLocalDB`,

I am grabbing it directly from my database using ef core, and storing it in  variable like so:

```
     var serverConn = dbSetting.CustomerConnectionSettings.ServerConnection;
```

serverConn has the string with the extra \\ causing my connection to fail,
Do i need to perform some sort of encoding/decoding?

Comment: Please clarify a) which character is being added, and b) where you're seeing this. In the debugger watch window, backslashes will be escaped because it's showing you a C# string literal. And why is the user entering a string with escaped backslashes?

Comment: extra \\ have been added as it says in my question, and the debugger shows the c# string literal, but the variable itself also contains the string literal when it is being used. @EdPlunkett

Comment: Please provide a complete code example and the inputs it's being given. We ordinarily don't like screenshots but I would like to see a screenshot of the place where you observe that "the variable itself also contains the string literal when it is being used". The good news is that there isn't a bug in the compiler or the framework that randomly adds backslashes at runtime.

Comment: Either 1. it is stored in the database with two slashes, so when it is read, C# needs to escape both of them, or 2. some custom code you have is escaping it twice. My bet is on the first one.

Comment: it is indeed stored with just 2 slashes in the db @Rhyous, do i need to store it diffrently? i thought ef core takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one slash when connecting to LocalDB (`(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB`). I think you (or the user) is thinking that you need to escape the slash like you do in code (e.g. `string conString = "(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB"`).

But if the connection string is stored somewhere, then you should just use one slash.  You will still *see* two slashes in the debugger, but if you print it out you'll see that there is indeed only one slash.

Answer (score 0):

C# will escape each slash with two slashes.

It doesn't need to be escaped in the database, so store it with 1 slash in the database.